# Why do we need refs to keep mutable objects around?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `useRef` [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) says it is handy for keeping any mutable value around. I was wondering why we can't just use a variable in the outer scope of the component for that purpose?

```
// the object I want to keep around
let obj;

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    obj =  //some code
  }, []);

  return (...)
}
```

It works, doesn't it? So why exactly is `useRef` better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable in the outer scope is shared between instances of your component. `useRef` will create a mutable object local to your component (and it will stay around as long as your component is mounted).